# Pull down menu using JavaScript CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a pull down menu which gets displayed and vanishes on a click.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kgu/Lhgk6r0p/)**

**JavaScript**

```
function visible(x) {
    var apple = document.getElementById('pulldown'+x);
    if (apple.style.display = "none")
    {
        apple.style.display = "block";
    }

}
```

This is working fine, but upon adding this to the above code -

```
else {
     apple.style.display = "none";
}
```

The `onclick` event only works once.

Comment: what about working this in jquery?

Comment: @CodeDemon     How is using Jquery better than this?

Answer (score 0):

use `==` inside the if condition rather than `=`

```
if (apple.style.display == "none")
```

Comment: You should use `===`. [See this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons). `==` does a type conversion so `'0' == 0` is true. However, you (almost) always want to use `===` which will give `'0' === 0` is false.

Answer (score 0):

how about achieve it with the power of jquery?

first we have element (anchor tag) that serve as a trigger and then the second element is the menu which hidden

html

```
<a href="#" class="pulldowntrigger">Pull down</a>
<div class="themenu" style="display: none;">menu content here</div>
```

jquery

```
// when click the anchor tag with a class pulldowntrigger
$('.pulldowntrigger').click(function(){
// check if the class themenu is hidden
if ($(this).next('.themenu')).is(":hidden"){
// yes its hidden! then slide it down (show)
$(this).next('.themenu').slideDown();
}else{
//nah! its not, then slide it up (hide)
$(this).next('.themenu').slideUp();
}
});
```